# How to sum up observations in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
Number State
42     AK
65     AK
31     TN
34     TN
12     MO
3      AK
41     MO
53     TN
23     AK
```

I would like to sum up the observations of State:

To see:

```
State Obs
AK    4
TN    3
MO    2
```

Comment: We can do `table(df1$State)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
#grouping rows by State
  group_by(State) %>%
#using 'n()' to count number of observations for each State
  summarize(Obs = n())
```

`Summarize()` function will keep only grouped variable *State* and summarization variable *Obs*.

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Number = c(42, 65, 31, 34, 12, 3, 41, 53, 23),
                  State = c("AK", "AK", "TN", "TN", "MO", "AK", "MO", "TN", "AK"))
```

Comment: Or `df1 %>% count(State)`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, that is much simpler solution, thank you. However, it is not enough if counting variable has to be named _Obs_ for some reason.